# Easy Identify The Movie

Tags: rebus

Source: [gpuzzles](https://gpuzzles.com/mind-teasers/puzzleOfTheDay/?source=stack)

Identify the movie name

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer can be

> 12 Angry Men 
>
>  12 time + angry(birds) Men(2 1/2 men)